# Using the integer data type

Tags: vb.net

I am writing a program that checks whether the user has entered a whole number, at the moment it works for everything apart from decimals. Even though I have declared it as an integer, the try statement is not catching the decimal as an exception. How do I fix this?

```
Sub Main()
  Dim Test As Integer
      Do
  Console.WriteLine("Enter a whole number")
     Try
        Test = Console.ReadLine()
        Exit Do
         Catch ex As Exception
              Console.WriteLine("You must enter a whole number")
              Console.WriteLine()
              Exit Try
        End Try
      Loop
   Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Comment: `Console.ReadLine` returns a string.  your code needs to validate it and convert it.  `Option Strict On` will help with this

Comment: Another one bites the dust. [_Option Strict Off_](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) kills again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use TryParse

```
   Dim number As Integer
   Dim result As Boolean = Int32.TryParse(Test, number)
   If result Then
        Console.WriteLine("You entered {0}.", number)
     Else
        Console.WriteLine("You must enter a whole number")
     End If
```